# After spring 5.2.3 upgrade, RequestParam values are coming twice in controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveAppConfiguration.abc", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String saveAppConfiguration(HttpServletRequest request,

@RequestParam("appName") String appName, //bbb,bbb

@RequestParam("privilege") String privilege,//abc,abc
    
@RequestParam("volumeName") String volumeName, @RequestParam("basePath") String basePath,//aa,aa
```

Every requestParam values come twice. Could anyone suggest what might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution, how far are correct needs to be checked.
I replaced @RequestParam with @ModelAttribute and it started taking value(without repetition)

```
        @ModelAttribute("appName") String appName, 

        @ModelAttribute("companyId") String companyId,
```

Comment: I have the same issue but I think your solution is more a work around as the RequestParam does not reflect the request reality.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Spring Framework 5.8.2. Some library were using spring-web 5.3.25 and others 5.3.26.

I setup the maven-enforcer-plugin and fix all possible issue with web and http related libraries. Then it start working. Was too lazy to change the hundred places where @RequestParam was used.

FYI:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>enforce</id>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <dependencyConvergence/>
                </rules>
                <fastFail>false</fastFail>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```